# limit input options in init() in swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I'm making a simple Dice class in swift.

I would like the Dice initializer to be called with the desired amount of eyes/sides the dice should have. I have two variables to set a min and max of number of sides you should be able to give the dice upon init...

However, I'm not quite sure of how to make the init fail if the dice is being initialized with a number outside of this range, when I can't make sue of try/catch in swift.

My code is as follows:

```
class Dice : SKSpriteNode {

    let sides : UInt32
    var score : Int

    init(sides : Int){

        let min_sides = 2
        let max_sides = 6

        self.sides = UInt32(sides)
        self.score = 1

        let imageName = "1.png"
        let cardTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)

        super.init(texture: cardTexture, color: nil, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        userInteractionEnabled = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **failable initializer** instead. From that you can return a `nil` value if the condition doesnt satisfied

```
    init?(sides : Int){

     if sides > max_sides{
           return nil
         }
    }
```

Comment: I kind of tried that but then it can't find the attributes for the SKSpriteNode. When i create a Dice like this:         dice.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2); addChild(dice); I get the following error: "'Dice' does not have a member named 'position'".

Comment: Now dice can be nil. So you have to make sure that it has a non nil value by conditional binding. if let currentDice = dice{ // use current dice here}

Comment: or you can use like `dice?.position` or you can store it to a property after conditional checking so you can avoid the use of `?` everywhere